# How to use stylelint with Grunt?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gruntjs, stylelint

I'm trying to replace [grunt-scss-lint](https://github.com/ahmednuaman/grunt-scss-lint) (because of its Ruby dependency and silent failure when you don't have the gem installed) with [stylelint](http://stylelint.io/).

The problem I'm running into is the following error:

```
$ grunt                                                                        
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: Map is not defined
```

I assume this is because stylelint (which is a PostCSS plugin, not a Grunt plugin) requires ES6.

[Here's the code that's throwing the `Map is not defined` error.](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/src/rules/indentation/index.js#L22)

Is there any way to get this to work where I can just run `grunt` and not some weird workaround [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751775/96257)?

Comment: I realize that stylelint requires all the new hotness, but I still don't know how to get that working with Grunt. https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint#requirements

Comment: Can you share your gruntfile.js please? I'm having a hard time hooking up grunt+stylelint+sass

Comment: Please edit the question with the relevant part of your gruntfile.js included. Your external link returns a 404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you just need to upgrade your version of Node. If you run 0.12 or higher, you shouldn't have troubles with Map. (The `--harmony` flag that makes that "weird workaround" weird is not required in 0.12+.)

The Node installation is independent of Grunt. Run `node -v` to see what's there. And if you need an upgrade, just use nodejs.org to get the latest.

Comment: Thank you so much, David! That did the trick. Hopefully my stupid question will be of help to other folks. :)

Comment: I'm sure you're not alone.